# Wireless: Asus PCE-AC68 on 13.10

Tags: wireless, networking, 13.10, asus, pcie

I purchased a http://www.asus.com/Networking/PCEAC68/ a few months back to use on my plex/backup/minecraft server, with the intention of also possibly using the server as a router.

I haven't had enough energy or patience to try messing with using it as a hotspot yet, because I haven't been able to get it to connect to my existing router to download updates and software.

It is seeing the available networks in my apartment just fine, but will not connect to my SSID.

The related bit of lspci:

```
03:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4360 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 03)
```

sudo dpkg -s bcmwl-kernel-source | grep Version

```
Version: 6.30.223.141+bdcom-0ubuntu1
```

My belkin usb adapter works just fine. (that's actually how I'm posting this)

Comment: Please edit your question to add your driver version: sudo dpkg -s bcmwl-kernel-source | grep Version

Comment: At this point, after following the instructions for the AC66 a second time, I can connect, but it is very unstable. The connection drops after 2-3 minutes, and my SSID disappears from the AP list until I disable and re-enable wireless.

Comment: What "driver name"should be used in hostapd to recognize this card?

Answer (score 1):

I got it to recognize the card using this ppa: https://launchpad.net/~albertomilone/+archive/broadcom

It has 6.30.223.30+bdcom-0ubuntu1~ppa1

Good luck